# Finding the minimum and maximum in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to ask the user to put some numbers and then print the size, sum, average, minimum and maximum. I can get the first 3 things but I'm stuck on the minimum and maximum one. The problem I have is I can't use `sort()` because I need to make the list an integer one, but you can't use an integer list for `split()`

Here's my code:

```
    number = raw_input('Enter number:')
    list_of_numbers = number.split()
    tally = 0
    sum = 0
      while number!= '':
        tally = tally + 1
        sum = sum + int(number)
        average = float(sum) / float(tally)
      number = raw_input('Enter number:')
    print "Size:", tally
    print "Sum:", sum
    print "Average:", average
```

Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Are you allowed to use built-in functions of Python? If yes, it is easier:

```
number = raw_input('Enter number:')
list_of_numbers = number.split()

numbersInt = map(int, list_of_numbers) # convert string list to integer list

print("Size:",    len(numbersInt))
print("Min:",     min(numbersInt))
print("Max:",     max(numbersInt))
print("Sum:",     sum(numbersInt))
print("Average:", float(sum(numbersInt))/len(numbersInt) if len(numbersInt) > 0 else float('nan'))
# float conversion is only required by Python 2.
```

where `numbersInt = map(int, list_of_numbers)` converts each string number of the list to an integer. Each function has the following meaning:

- **`len`** computes the length of a list
- **`min`** computes the minimum
- **`max`** computes the maximum
- **`sum`** computes the sum of a list

There isn't a mean function in Python standard library. But you can use `numpy.mean()` instead. Install it with `pip install numpy` or `conda install numpy`, then:

```py
import numpy as np
print("Average: ", np.mean(numbersInt))
```

Comment: This is most pythonic way and most efficient one.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use min() and max() to find those values.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- You could compare the current number to the previous extrema and update your minimum and maximum accordingly;

  ```
  import sys
  tally = 0
  sum = 0
  nmax = -sys.maxint
  nmin = +sys.maxint
  number = raw_input('Enter number:')
  while number!= '':
      number = int(number)
      if number > nmax:
          nmax = number
      elif number < nmin:
          nmin = number
      tally = tally + 1
      sum += number
      average = float(sum) / float(tally)
      number = raw_input('Enter number:')
  ```

  We use the largest integer on your system (`sys.maxint`) to initialize our `nmin` and `nmax`
- You could store each number in a list, then perform all the operations at once:

  ```
  number = raw_input('Enter number:')
  numbers = []
  while number!= '':
      numbers.append(int(number))
      number = raw_input('Enter number:')
  numbers.sort()
  nmin = numbers[0]
  nmax = numbers[-1]
  tally = len(numbers)
  nsum = sum(numbers)
  avg = nsum/float(tally)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This may be with least complexity if I am not wrong.

```
len_min_max_sum=reduce(lambda x,y : (x[0]+1,y,x[2],x[3]+y) if x[0]>y else (x[0]+1,x[1],y,x[3]+y) if x[2]<y else (x[0]+1,x[1],x[2],x[3]+y) ,arr,(0,arr[0],arr[0],0))

len_min_max_sum_avg=(len_min_max_sum[0],len_min_max_sum[1],len_min_max_sum[2],len_min_max_sum[3],float(len_min_max_sum[3])/len_min_max_sum[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tally = 0
sum = 0
average = 0
while (True):
    number = input('Enter number')
    list_of_numbers = number.split()
    if number == '':
        continue
    else:
        tally = tally + 1
        sum = sum + int(number)
        average = float(sum)/float(tally)
    print('Size:', tally)
    print('Sum:', sum)
    print('Average:', average)
```

Comment: Please edit your indentation. It is crucial for Python.

Answer (score 0):

The `max()` and `min()` predefined math methods in python can solve this 
as below

```
numbers = [3,2,5,9,5,3]
minimum = min(numbers)
maximum = max(numbers)
```

result of the above is

```
>>>maximum
9
>>>minimum
2
```

Hope that helps.